# Why is this Javascript not adding in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This script will create a new element and give it the correct ID, but will not load in the HTML/string below:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#test img").on("click", function (e) {
        var titleEl = document.createElement("div");
        var laptopImg = $("#test img");
        var theText = "<p>this is a test</p>"
        document.body.appendChild(titleEl);
        titleEl.id = "img-title";
        titleEl.html = theText;
        titleEl.position = laptopImg.position;
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#img-title {
    color:black;
    z-index:1;
}
#test img {
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
}
#test img:hover {
    transform: scale(.5,.5);
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
}
#test img:active {
    -moz-transform:skew(360);
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
}
</style>
<div id="test">
    <%= image_tag('test_2.jpg') %>
</div>
```

I have tried various functions such as .val .appendChild, ect... But none seem to work. It just creates a new empty div each time I click on the image.

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and native DOM methods? Also, the properties `.html` and `.position` do not exist - that's  why it doesn't work.

Comment: it should be `titleEl.innerHTML = theText ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a raw solution, you need to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

```
$(function() { 
    $("#test img").on("click", function(e) {

        var titleEl = document.createElement("div");
        var laptopImg = $("#test img");
        var theText = "<p>this is a test</p>"
        document.body.appendChild(titleEl);
        titleEl.id = "img-title";
        titleEl.innerHTML = theText ;
        titleEl.style.position = laptopImg.css('position'); 

    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MS3ZY/)

A jQuery-ish solution will

```
$(function () {
    var $laptopImg = $("#test img").on("click", function (e) {
        var theText = "<p>this is a test</p>"
        $div = $('<div />', {
            id: 'img-title',
            position: $laptopImg.css('position'),
            html: theText
        }).appendTo('body')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T52Rq/)

Note: Also need to make sure there are no duplicate ID's if multiple clicks are done

Comment: @Stuart neater, I like it

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should add the div for you

```
$(function() { 
    $("#test img").on("click", function(e) {
        var laptopImg = $("#test img");

        $('<div id="img-title"><p>this is a test</p></div>')
            .appendTo(document.body)
            .css('position', 'absolute')
            .offset(laptopImg.offset());
    });
});
```